# Loop through all images inside links, extract image name from the image path and convert it into a string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
 $("a > img").each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("alt") == undefined || $(this).attr("alt") == "") {
      var name = $(this).attr('src');
      name.replace(/(\/+\.+\-+)w+?/, "");
      $(this).attr('alt', name);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am trying to get all images inside a link that don't have an ALT tag. Then get the image name as a string and add it as ALT tag to the image. Everything works fine except for the regular expression. Right now it's adding the image path as an ALT which doesn't fix my ADA issues.
The reason i am doing that is because i am trying to fix the ADA issues on the website. (Every image inside a link must have an alt tag)

Comment: There are no anchors or images in your snippet, so it's not doing a great job reproducing your issue...

Answer (score 0):

You need to reassign the updated value after replace to `name` variable again and then update the image `alt` attribute like:

```
name = name.replace(/(\/+\.+\-+)w+?/, "");
$(this).attr('alt', name);
```

Answer (score 0):

// If a link has an image and no aria label 
//Get image source, strip everything except for image name
//Add image name as aria-label to the link[image]

```
    $('a:has(> img)').each(function () {
        var URL = $(this).children('img').prop('src');
        var output = URL.split('/').pop();
        output = output.replace(/[- .\s]/g, " ");
        $(this).attr('aria-label', output);
    });
```